# Calculate all possible cuboids

Tags: algorithm, 3d, packaging, cube

I'm currently working on a packaging algorithm, where cubic items have to be placed inside one bigger package. It is possible to turn the items.

Also, I want to consider every sub-cube which is bounded by another cube or the package as a candidate for the placement of the next item. Because the items can overlap each other the amount of sub-cubes isn't growing linearly with the amount of items placed into the package-bin. As the cube-candidates get smaller with the number of placed items, the items are placed in descending order of their volume.

Do you guys know of an algorithm or paper dealing the calculation of all cubes inside a "cubic 3D landscape"?

Comment: A paper on packing I've used in the past is http://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~rharren/publications/Harren-StudentResearchPaper.pdf

But I'm not sure it's necessarily the most optimal solution in a cube only scenario. If the cubes are all multiples of the smallest size of there is a common factor that isn't ridiculously small, I would personally head down the voxelisation route with constraints based on voxel clusters. rather than in continuous space. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the guillotine algorithm. You can search for optimization guillotine algorithm. There is a paper you can download:https:http://clb.demon.fi/files/RectangleBinPack.pdf. Sorry, its only 2d bin-packing.